# COUNT(*)=0 evaluates to true?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

Just like the title says. I have a SQL statement (Oracle 9) in an if statement that evaluates to true. From what I recall such a statement would do what is expected in SQL Server. What am I doing wrong in this case?

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUSTOMER_LIST WHERE CUSTOMER='Target')=0 THEN  
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_LIST (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER) VALUES
(CUSTOMER_ID_SEQ.nextval, 'Target')
```

or better yet, what is an appropriate strategy to ensure that I do not insert data that already exists. The code as written always inserts. This obviously is not what I want since this row exists already.

When this code runs I get the following console message.

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUSTOMER_LIST WHERE CUSTOMER='Target')=0 THEN
Error report:
Unknown Command
1 rows inserted.
```

Comment: I am currently despising it compared to MSSQL but alas I don't get to choose my employer's db :'(

Comment: Is that the whole block, or is there more code?  `IF` is a PL/SQL command, and so needs to have BEGIN and END around the whole block at least.

Comment: is `CUSTOMER` not an `UNIQUE` field? … if it is, you can just try the `INSERT` and count rows returned (0 or 1)…?

Comment: Around the "IF"? I get ORA-06550: line 2, column 63:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * @ % & - + ; / at for mod rem <an exponent (**)> and or
   group having intersect minus order start union where connect
   ||
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action: when I do that

Comment: @BRPocock If I do that what is the natural behavior? Will Oracle throw an exception on duplicates? It was one of the ways I was considering to handle this.

Comment: Try `IF NOT Exists(SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_LIST WHERE CUSTOMER='Target')`.

Comment: I would expect Oracle to just return "0 rows inserted," but it might have an exception for that; and/or your database access layer might give you options about how to handle duplicates (DBI, mysqli, JDBC, whatever)

Comment: @DourHighArch I get Error starting at line 1 in command:
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_LIST WHERE CUSTOMER='Target') THEN
Error report:
Unknown Command
1 rows inserted.
 using that approach. Damn I wish my sql skills were stronger.

Comment: What about setting up a constraint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're giving it PL/SQL where it's expecting straight SQL. Either give it straight SQL:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_LIST (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER)
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID_SEQ.nextval, 'Target' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CUSTOMER_LIST WHERE CUSTOMER = 'Target')
```

or else change the surrounding context so that Oracle will expect PL/SQL. That will depend on how you're passing this code in; but one likely way is to wrap it in a `BEGIN ... END` block.

Additionally, you can't use a query as an expression in PL/SQL; if you go the PL/SQL route, you'll need to store the result somewhere, such as in a variable. All told, you might have this:

```
DECLARE
  v_customer_exists INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_customer_exists FROM CUSTOMER_LIST WHERE CUSTOMER='Target';
  IF v_customer_exists = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_LIST (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER) VALUES
    (CUSTOMER_ID_SEQ.nextval, 'Target');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    DECLARE
       v_count number;

    BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM CUSTOMER_LIST WHERE CUSTOMER='Target';

    IF v_count = 0 THEN
      INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_LIST (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER) VALUES
(CUSTOMER_ID_SEQ.nextval, 'Target');
    END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: I get Error starting at line 4 in command:
END IF
Error report:
Unknown Command

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to check if any rows are returned from the selection. NOT EXISTS returns true when no tuples were returned from the select:

```
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_LIST WHERE CUSTOMER='Target') THEN  
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_LIST (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER) VALUES
(CUSTOMER_ID_SEQ.nextval, 'Target')
```